# Не работает код php пишет ошибку

Tags: php, mysql

Написало вот это в браузере:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\bd.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\save_user.php(18): include() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\bd.php on line 2

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db ("mysql",$db);
?>
```

И вот save_user.php 18 строка

```
include ("bd.php");//
```

Comment: У вас не установлено расширение mysql. Ну а в целом используйте mysqli. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @rjhdby пхп 7 там возможно используется

Comment: как добавить расширение mysql?

Comment: Ну или используйте PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Из PHP7 все функции ext/mysql были удалены. Для выбора альтернативного MySQL API, читайте раздел [Выбор MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) на официальном сайте.

Если версия меньше, чем php7, то не установлено расширение связанное с подключением к БД.

Расширение mysql представляет потенциальную опасность для вашего кода. Используйте PDO, mysqli

Comment: Простите, но как установить расширение связанное с подключением к БД?

Comment: @ВладимирМирош Из командной строки для php7 - sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте файл php.ini

Найдите строчку:
;extension=php_mysql.dll, снимите с нее точку с запятой, если она там есть.

А вообще, переходите на [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).