# Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

Казус. Локально этот код работал. Загрузил на хостинг ошибка указывает на 4 строку.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "2") or die (mysql_error ());
```

Пишет

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: Похожие: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662372/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522542/186083

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии **PHP 5.5.0**, и **удалено в PHP 7.0.0**. Используйте вместо него **MySQLi** или **PDO_MySQL**. Может на хостинге стоит 7 версия **PHP**.

Используйте `mysqli_connect()`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)